# JQuery Column Calculations

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need some assistance with this code:
http://jsfiddle.net/N5xTJ/1/

The last column already is dynamic through jQuery, which calculates "Packs QTY" x "Price", then totals on the bottom.

I need help doing the calculation for total QTY based on `<TD CLASS="QTY">` and it will show results in `totalsqty`.

Also for `TotalUnits` Needs to calculate "Qty" X "Units Per Pack" and show in "Total Units".

JS that is currently doing the totals for `#Total Price`:

```
function ca(){
    var $overall = 0;

    $("tr.sum").each(function() {
         var $row=$(this);
        var $qnt = $(this).find(".qty");
        var cost = $row.data('unit_price');        
        
        var sum = cost * parseFloat($qnt.val());

        $(this).find("td").eq(5).text('$' +sum);

        $overall += sum;

    });

    $("#total").text('$' +$overall);
}

$(function() {

    ca();
    $('input.qty').bind('change keyup', ca);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N5xTJ/4/

I've updated your existing code, to accommodate `totalUnits` and `totalQty`.

**Code (with comments):**

```
    function ca() {
    var $overall = 0,
        totalQty = 0,
        totalUnits = 0;

    $("tr.sum").each(function() {
        var $row = $(this),
            qnt = parseInt($(this).find("input.qty").val()),
            cost = $row.data('unit_price'),
            sum = cost * qnt,
            upp = parseInt($row.find('.upp').text());


        $row.find('span.t-units').text(upp * qnt);
        $(this).find("td").eq(5).text('$' + sum);
        totalQty += qnt;
        totalUnits += parseInt($row.find('span.t-units').text());
        $overall += sum;

    });

    $("#total").text('$' + $overall);
    $('#totalqty').text(totalQty);
    $('#totalunits').text(totalUnits);
}

$(function() {

    ca();
    $('input.qty').bind('change keyup', ca);

});​
```

I've also cleaned up the code a bit, so have a look and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Whoa, fast. Thank you for the help.

Comment: The column to the right of the input box should update based on qty x units per pack = total unit. I put in 12 and 24 to show a example.

It would be class "upp" x class "input qty" = class "t-units"

Comment: I add
 tunits += parseInt($(this).find('.upp').text());
and 

  $('#tunits').text(tunits);
But it doesnt seem to work.
Here is a forked fiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/GhpgY/

Comment: Have updated the code, so have a look and let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Can you update one more time. I believe i saved over it before i saw this

Comment: Yeah, the above fiddle is the latest. Here it is again: http://jsfiddle.net/N5xTJ/4/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CQRda/4/ 

) I added it to my site and did a $row.data change and now i am getting NAN for the Tunits and TotalUnits. Where is it not getting a number?

Comment: I just tried to change it using data-upp instead of a column/row